# Error using Spray's IO HTTP actor

Tags: akka, spray

I'm connecting to one of the Twitter streaming APIs using a single Akka actor, which then farms out the processing of each tweet to another actor for processing.

I am occasionally seeing errors where Twitter is closing the HTTP connection - the reason it does this is because at times I believe my connection is reading data from the stream too slowly

> Twitter will close a streaming connection for the following reasons:
>
> If the rate of Tweets being read off of the stream drops suddenly, the connection
>   will be closed.
>
> A client reads data too slowly. 
>   Every streaming connection is backed by a queue of messages to be sent to the client.
>   If this queue grows too large over time, the connection will be
>   closed.

Here is my stack trace:

```
[WARN] [08/23/2014 17:04:43.104] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://default/user/IO-HTTP/host-connector-0/0] Aborted in response to POST request to /1.1/statuses/filter.json with no retries left, dispatching error...
    spray.can.Http$ConnectionException: Aborted
        at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot.reportDisconnection(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:215)
        at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot$$anonfun$connected$1.applyOrElse(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:163)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage_aroundBody0(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell$AjcClosure1.run(ActorCell.scala:1)
        at org.eigengo.monitor.agent.akka.ActorCellMonitoringAspect.ajc$around$org_eigengo_monitor_agent_akka_ActorCellMonitoringAspect$1$5ea23d46proceed(ActorCellMonitoringAspect.aj:72)
        at org.eigengo.monitor.agent.akka.ActorCellMonitoringAspect.ajc$around$org_eigengo_monitor_agent_akka_ActorCellMonitoringAspect$1$5ea23d46(ActorCellMonitoringAspect.aj:95)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I am wondering how I would deal with the scenario of the connection being closed? I'm guessing a supervisor actor who restarts the stream reading actor when it's closed is probably my best option.

What I was wondering though, is is there a way for my stream reading actor to split the load or have multiple actors processing the same stream of data?

How can I determine whether my actor system is fast enough to keep up with demand?

Comment: there is a `activator template` that deals with twitter stream processing. Have you checked on that?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm using and getting the connection error from occasionally. I've added the stack trace to my question.

Comment: If you didn't do anything special, the spray-level HTTP connection will greedily read everything from the connection which would mean that data would stack up in the queue's of your processing Actor. However, twitter wouldn't notice so I wonder if that's really the reason for twitter closing the connection.